# how to force MongoDB (3.0.4) to display a specific field value?

Tags: mongodb

This question is not about projecting specific fields.
I'm experiencing some rather bizarre MongoDB behavior.
Consider this:

`db.call_data.findOne()` :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56dddbda8a09bc202b05fb47"),
  "FIELD1" : "ASINC0000710793", "HPD_SUBMITTER" : "blah",
  "person_id" : "PPL000000021124",
  "Resolved_date" : "2014-04-17 05:07:19.000",
  "owner_group" : "Service Desk - Incident Management Team",
  "submitter" : "blah", "submit_date" : "2014-04-17 05:07:32.000",
  "reported_date" : "2014-04-17 05:06:06.000",
  "Call_Duration" : 86, "resolution_category" : "NULL",
  "resolution_category_tier_2" : "NULL", 
  "resolution_category_tier_3" : "NULL", 
  "CATEGORIZATION_TIER_1" : "Application",
  "CATEGORIZATION_TIER_2" : "System",
  "CATEGORIZATION_TIER_3" : "Single User Affected",
  "Description" : "VDI  unable to logon",
  "Escalated" : "NULL"
}
```

Then, when I issue `db.call_data.distinct("FIELD1")`, I get `[ ]`

Or, if I issue `db.call_data.find({FIELD1: 'ASINC0000710793'})`, I get nothing back.

How do I deal with this?

Comment: just to clarify - there is no blank space beforeFIELD1, as it appears in my example. that was just an artifact of copy/paste

Comment: you have a space in front of FIELD1 - otherwise where did it come from?  If it's not there, humor us, cut-and-paste it again.  Or run db.call_data.distinct(" FIELD1")

Comment: You are correct. I have created a gist, and, as I was pasting the JSON, I have noticed the space again, which does not appear in JSON view:  https://gist.github.com/eugene-goldberg/874de39ba1bed24a6457

Comment: @Asya - if you post your comment as answer, I'll be happy to accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json strings aka keys or field names can legally have spaces in them.  It looks like yours had a leading space which is hard to spot.    Confirming it via using quoted field in query will help.